# Extract multiple strings from variable divided by vertical line

Tags: javascript, regex, for-loop, google-tag-manager

On our client's website there is a javascript variable with page categories divided by vertical line. Here is example:

```
category_name = "Products|Healthy|Chia pudding";
```

I need to extract those categories and put it into separate variables:

```
category_name_1 = "Products";
category_name_2 = "Healthy";
category_name_3 = "Chia pudding";
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function

```
category_name_array = category_name.split("|"); 
     -> ["Products", "Healthy", "Chia pudding"]
```

and then you can access it like this:

```
console.log(category_name_array[0]); -> "Products"
console.log(category_name_array[1]); -> "Healthy"
console.log(category_name_array[2]); -> "Chia pudding"
```

Comment: Completely forgot about `split()` function! Thank you.

Comment: No problem :D, happens to the best ones

Answer (score 0):

Using ES.next destructuring:

```
const [
    category_name_1, 
    category_name_2,
    category_name_3
] = category_name.split('|');
```

Using ES5 syntax:

```
var names = category_name.split('|');
var category_name_1 = names[0];
var category_name_2 = names[1];
var category_name_3 = names[2];
```

The better way of doing this would be to just use a simple array instead of variables tho. So using the example above, whenever you need the first category, just use `names[0]` to refer to it.